# Recurrence of states in a function of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose $X$ is a Markov chain (or process, for that matter) and suppose further $f(X)$ is also a Markov chain. Let $s$ be a recurrent state in $X$. Is there a general way to determine the recurrence status of $f(s)$ in $f(X)$?
The motivation behind my question is the simple symmetric random walk in $\Bbb Z$ as $X$ and $f(X)=|X|$. Unless I'm mistaken, both chains are irreducible and recurrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That $s$ is recurrent means that $X$ visits $s$ with full probability. Thus,  $f(X)$ visits $f(s)$ with full probability, that is, $f(s)$ is recurrent for $f(X)$.

Comment: So simple. I'll edit $s$ to $f(s)$ by the way, thank you.